# Identifying exact type of transistor

Tags: transistors, identification, siemens

I can not identify the exact model of this transistor. 
[image]
It reacts as a bipolar NPN Si transistor with EBC pin configuration (first image left to right,) not ECB! This seems to be made by Siemens. Package is TO92.

Any idea?

It's from old store, just found plenty ot them ~500pcs. I did successful test:  middle to left p-n junction ~0.6V; middle to right p-n junction ~0.6V; also LED test -ok. 
Аlso the diode glimmers at base current through the fingers.
[image: schematic]

I think these transistors were prepared for mounting and then abandoned due to the unusual configuration of the pins. You can see the cut pins of the exact length. It's kind of like a rare coin.[image]

Comment: +1 for great quality photo's. If only everybody would provide images that good. By the way, you are right: that is a Siemens logo.

Comment: Could it be a SIEMENS BF420? https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/126135/SiemensSemiconductorGroup/BF420/1

Comment: @Verbal Kint: Might be but pinout is EBC not ECB...  -???

Comment: Also made by ON semi and former Philips.

Comment: Where does this transistor come from? I assume you probe the pinout with a multimeter in \$V_f\$ mode?

Comment: Here's a link to what seems to be the PNP equivalent https://www.ebay.ie/itm/10x-BF421-Siemens-PNP-Silicon-Transistor-High-Breakdown-Voltage-/172270962538. Very similar markings.  So, I'm going with Verbal, I think it's the BF420 NPN.